# MongoParseError: option usenewuriparser is not supported at parseOptions

Tags: mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QprWv.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tq1H.png)

[I was expected to get listening to PORT 8080 DB Connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtoyo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [`useNewUriParser` was depreciated in v6.0.0](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options) of mongoose. I do not see any information about the version you are using, but if you are using a version >= 6.0.0, it's no longer needed:

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // <-- no longer necessary
  useUnifiedTopology: true // <-- no longer necessary
});
```

Also the options are case sensitive, you typed useNewUr**I**Parser, instead of  `useNewUriParser`.

Next time, include your code as snippets in the question :)